# How do I send assign a List<string> to a JavaScript array or enumerable object

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I have the following :

```
ViewBag.SomeEnumerable = new List<string>() { "string1", "string2" };
```

Now how do I assign `ViewBag.SomeEnumerable` to an `array` or some form of enumerable object on the JavaScript side? e.g.:

```
function SomeFunction()
{
  var array = @ViewBag.SomeEnumerable;
  for(var eachItem in array)
  {
    alert(eachItem); // should display "string1" then string2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SomeFunction() {
    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.SomeEnumerable));
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        alert(array[i]); // should display "string1" then string2"
    }
}
</script>
```

will be rendered as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SomeFunction() {
    var array = ["string1","string2"];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        alert(array[i]); // should display "string1" then string2"
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: VS is giving `syntax error at ;` when i declare var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.SomeEnumerable)); however o/p is correct in html rendered in browser

Comment: @IshaanPuniani, why do you even trust VS Intellisense? It is wrong. Look at the rendered markup to see that it is correct despite VS telling you it is wrong.